# Create a box from a flutter .hive file stored in the cache

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I know this may sound simple but I have a hive file (which I got from the File Picker package) and now, based on this hive file, I want to load the Box. Is there an easy way to just load the box from the hive file? Something like:

`Box newBox= await Hive.openBox('boxName', path: hiveFile.path)`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to open your new `Hive` box:

```
  final box = await Hive.openBox<T>("boxExmapleName");
```

This box now will have its own file saved locally, and until now it's empty, right, we can get it's path with:

```
final boxPath = box.path;
```

Now, after we had its path, we **need to close that box, so we can make changes to its file properly**:

```
await box.close();
```

Until this, we have the box path, and it's closed, then we can copy set our personnel `Hive` box file into that `box` that we just created:

```
    File("HERE THE PATH OF THE PERSONNEL HIVE BOX").copy(boxPath);
```

Change "HERE THE PATH OF THE PERSONNEL HIVE BOX" with the path of your hive file.

This will copy that file into  the created `box` file.

so combining it as a method:

```
Future<void> HiveBoxFromFile<T>(String boxName, String PathOfFile) async {
  final box = await Hive.openBox<T>(boxName);
  final boxPath = box.path;
  await box.close();

  try {
    File(PathOfFile).copy(boxPath);
  } finally {
    await Hive.openBox<T>(boxName); // this is to re-open the box again after the operation is finished
  }
}
```

Now you should use the `box` in your app, and it will have the data that was in the file.